# Connecting phone in mass storage mode

Tags: usb, android, usb-drive

I am trying to connect [Xiaomi Rednote](http://www.xiaomishop.com/144-xiaomi-redmi-note-4g-lte-martphone.html) phone using USB cable.
I would like to connect the phone using mass storage mode to copy big amount of data to the SD card.

If followed a [tutorial](http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=15786&page=1#pid333316) to enable Mass storage mode on the phone and I am able to do it successfully. 
Now when I connect the phone to my Ubuntu 14 laptop, I get following in the `dmesg` -

```
[ 5114.621717] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[ 5114.715002] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2717, idProduct=1328
[ 5114.715010] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5114.715015] usb 2-1.2: Product: HM NOTE 1LTEW
[ 5114.715019] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Xiaomi
[ 5114.715024] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: xxxxxxx
[ 5114.715910] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 5114.716411] scsi16 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.1
```

However, I am unable to see any folders where I can access the SD-card. I tried to search how do I mount this drive, but I am unable to get any information.
Maybe I am doing something wrong or the phone does not support mass storage?

Just a small note that I am able to connect it in MTP mode.

output of `sudo sg_scan`

```
/dev/sg0: scsi0 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em]
/dev/sg1: scsi1 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em]
```

Can anyone give some pointers to check this?